# How to check whether header() has been set in PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers

Is there possible whether there are some header information set so far in PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `headers_sent()`.

PHP docs on [headers_sent()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php).

You can also retrieve the headers for a page with [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) and list them with [headers_list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php). I'm a bit confused though, do you mean you want to check if something like `header("Location: /path/to/location");` has been called?

Comment: This is about **sent**, but I'm asking about **set**, a little different,right?

Comment: There are a variety of header functions, can you be more specific about what you need to check? Some code maybe?

Comment: @user what do you mean under "set"?

Answer (score 5):

Try using [header_list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) to determine what headers are ready to be sent to the client.
Use [headers_sent()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) to check if headers have been sent to the client.